# Sending message to a specific ID in Socket.IO 1.0

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I want to sent data to one specific socket ID.

We used to be able to do this in the older versions:

```
io.sockets.socket(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only');
```

How would I go about doing something similar in Socket.IO 1.0?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

In socket.io 1.0 they provide a better way for this. Each socket automatically joins a default room by self id. Check documents: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-room

So you can emit to a socket by id with following code:

```
io.to(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only');
```

Comment: There is difference between to (room_id) and (user_socket_id)? I actually use it to send message to a room that can have one or more users. "This makes it easy to broadcast messages to other sockets:", then can be one or more, not a unique private one.

Comment: @WashingtonBotelho, socket IDs usually look something like "Uj5CRqZ5b_Xubx9sAAAA", so in theory there are might be more than one user in such room, but in practice I don't know any cases when I would add a user to other user's personal room.

Comment: How can we identify a specific user by their socketId, does this mean we need to store a key value pair of user (for eg-username) and socketId somewhere?

Comment: @Mustafa Dokumacı merhaba, bana bir yardim et http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817680/nodejs-could-not-detect-online-soket

Comment: It's just so unlogic... why don't just provide us a way to send a message to a socket id number and that's it? Anyway upvoted, the only work around that actually works on 2.x

Comment: @Sai I know this is kind of old, but the array.prototype.find() method may help

Answer (score 95):

In socket.io 1.0 you can do that with following code:

```
if (io.sockets.connected[socketid]) {
    io.sockets.connected[socketid].emit('message', 'for your eyes only');
}
```

**Update:**

@MustafaDokumacı's answer contains a better solution.

Comment: The difference between this answer and pointed better answer is that with THIS solution, you can have callbacks which is nice. But with io.to(socketid), you CAN'T use callbacks.

Answer (score 17):

@Mustafa Dokumacı and @Curious already provided enough information, I am adding how you can get socket id.

To get socket id use **socket.id**:

```
var chat = io.of("/socket").on('connection',onSocketConnected);

function onSocketConnected(socket){
   console.log("connected :"+socket.id);  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have used a namespace I found that the following works :

```
//Defining the namespace <br>
var nsp = io.of('/my-namespace');

//targeting the message to socket id <br>
nsp.to(socket id of the intended recipient).emit('private message', 'hello');
```

More about namespaces:
http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Answer (score 6):

I believe both @Curious and @MustafaDokumacı provided solutions that work well. The difference though is that with @MustafaDokumacı's solution the message is broadcasted to a room and not only to a particular client.

The difference is prominent when an acknowledgement is requested.

```
io.sockets.connected[socketid].emit('message', 'for your eyes only', function(data) {...});
```

works as expected, while

```
io.to(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only', function(data) {...});
```

fails with

```
Error: Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting
```

Answer (score 2):

in Node.js --> socket.io --> there is a chat example to download 
Paste this in line  (io on connection) part..  i use this code that works 100%

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log(socket.id);
    io.to(socket.id).emit('chat message', msg+' you ID is:'+socket.id);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

## Update Socket.io v4.0+

```
var socketById = io.sockets.sockets.get(id);
socketById.emit("message", "hi")
```

This is the optimal way to get a socket by ID in v4 and emitting to it.