# socket.IO: how can i get the socketid when i emit to a specific client in socket.io 1.0

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I want to emit a action to a specific client using socket.io 1.0.

After reading [Sending message to a specific ID in Socket.IO 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041220/sending-message-to-a-specific-id-in-socket-io-1-0) , I know I can use:

```
io.sockets.connected[socketid].emit()
```

to emit a action to specific person.

But how can I get the `socketid`?

I used to write like this : `socket.id=nickName`, but it's wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply access `id` property of `socket` object:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log(socket.id);
});
```

Comment: Ok, but why after i use 'socket.id = nickName', when i tried to emit to the new id i failed? is this socketid cannot to change?

Comment: Yes `socket.id` should not be changed, but if you want you can write `socket.nickName = nickName`