# Any document, blogs, study notes or summary for socket.io 1.0

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I know this question has been asked [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363466/socket-io-documentation/).

But it's two years ago. The new version 1.0 has been released for a long time. [The official docs](http://socket.io/docs/) still don't have everything on it.

I think maybe someone have summarize some study notes or whatever useful.

This is what I collected in stackoverflow:

1.[Get a room's clients list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858604/how-to-get-rooms-clients-list-in-socket-io-1-0/)   or  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135188/socket-io-how-can-i-get-the-socketid-when-i-emit-to-a-specific-client-in-socket)

2.[Emit to a specific client](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-room) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221820/io-sockets-socketsocket-id-emit-has-no-method-socket/)

3.[Get a list of all the namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081622/list-of-namespaces-in-socket-io/)

Any feature or help would be appreciated

Comment: http://socket.io/docs/, what more do you need?

Comment: More than [socket.io/docs](http://socket.io/docs/) , the official docs only mentioned the basic part of socket.io

Comment: We must all agree the CURRENT official socket.io documentation is a joke.