# Emit to a specific client with socketId via Socket.IO 1.0

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I know it's very popular question, but i didn't find answer for my question.
Very similar question: 
[socket.IO: how can i get the socketid when i emit to a specific client in socket.io 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135188/socket-io-how-can-i-get-the-socketid-when-i-emit-to-a-specific-client-in-socket)

I want emit to a specific client with socketId, But i get an error, see below.

```
socket.join( gameId );
io.sockets.connected( opponent ).join( gameId );
socket.emit( 'ready', gameId, 'X', x, y );
io.sockets.connected( opponent ).emit( 'ready', gameId, 'O', x, y );
```

Error:

```
          io.sockets.connected( opponent ).join( gameId );
                     ^
TypeError: Property 'connected' of object #<Namespace> is not a function
```

Please help me.
Forgot to say that, impossible to use `.join(gameId)` with `io.to(socket.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To join a room**

```
socket.on('someEventName', function(Param){
    try {
        socket.join('A_Temporary_Room');    
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

**To send a message to all members in this room**

```
io.sockets.in('A_Temporary_Room').emit('ready', 'String');
```

***EDIT***

```
socket.on('setId', function(SocketId) {
    socket.set('socketId', SocketId, function(data){
        //callback
        /* Here you can maintain an array of all connected clients like
            clients[SocketId].push(socket); Where clients is an object.
         */
    });
});
```

Now to emit an event to a specific client use this

```
clients[SocketId].emit('PrivateMessage', 'This is a private message');
```

Comment: At my application the server is deciding when socket should be added to the room.Feel the difference! 
So again, i have pool of socketsID, and i want to emit to specific client an event "join the room".
PLEASE, don't ignore magic word "specific"...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I totally get your question, but you can emit to a specific socket id by emitting to the default room of the socket. Every socket is joining a default room with the id of the socket as name.

http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-room