# Socket.io rooms vs namespaces

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am making a browser game using nodejs and socket.io. I am trying to add "rooms" to my game so players can choose what kind of gamemode to play. What I am wondering is if I should be using a socket.io namespace for each gamemode or should I use socket.io rooms to get this done, or is there a better way to do this?
Thanks alot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [socket.io rooms or namespacing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930286/socket-io-rooms-or-namespacing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending message to a specific ID in Socket.IO 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041220/sending-message-to-a-specific-id-in-socket-io-1-0)