# How to start socket.io learning?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I'm a new comer to socket.io over node.js 
I found that the documentaion of socket.io in its website isn't good enough to start 
is there a good referncies to start with socket.io in real projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the tutorial I remember following.  It's nicely broken down and the stages are well explained - and it leads to a working example (open lots of browser Windows to see it working).

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socketio-and-expressjs--net-31708

Comment: is there any other referencies for socket.io api associated with sample codes espicially rooms and namespaces?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930286/socket-io-rooms-or-namespacing

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out what codeschool has to offer... https://www.codeschool.com/courses/real-time-web-with-node-js They have great content and an easy to learn interface for newbies.

Comment: I think you should point out that codeschool is a subscription service.